# How to properly set $_GET variables from URL with added GET variables

Tags: php, url, variables, get

If I'm setting up a

```
if(isset($_GET['var']))
{
 //stuff with only 1 variable
}
```

How do I properly set it so if my url is something like

```
http://www.url.com/test.php?var=something&var2=somethingelse
```

So when this url has 2 get variables, it should not show the block of codes that is within isset($_GET['var']). Instead, it should show the code in this block

```
if(isset($_GET['var']) && isset($_GET['var2']))
{
 // block of codes with 2 variables
}
```

However, the first block of codes will be shown as well because there's nothing from telling that it shouldn't show if there's other variables.

Comment: I didn't understand this part, (It won't show anything in the 1 variable, because if I only have isset($_GET['var']), then it will show everything in there even if there is more variables added to the URL )

Comment: @softgenic sorry, I ment, it WILL show everything in that isset($_GET['var'])

Comment: okay what you want is when two varaibles are passed by url then it should run for `$var1 && $var2` and should ignore `$var1`. In that case you can use `if (isset($var1) && !isset($var2)) { then code will run for if 2nd varaiable is not there }`

Comment: @softgenic the issue with that is what if user decides to mess with the URL and just adds other variables? and not only var2, but some other variables.. the code you show does not prevent user from seeing the blog if they have some other variable in the URL like `?var=something&var4=something` now they have var4 and not just var2

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['var']) && count($_GET) == 1) {
    //stuff with only 1 variable
}
```

However, doing this is a pretty bad idea. It breaks your site in case some other unknown GET variable is present. While that is not *that* likely I wouldn't expect any site to break from it.

For example, ad servers might automatically add one to allow the target site to create statistics if they want to.

If you know which other variables to expect (which should be the case) better explicitely check for them not being present:

```
if(isset($_GET['var']) && !isset($_GET['var2'])) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Would this be the only way to do so? Because I plan on adding ads in the future, and if that's the case, how would you resolve this issue?

Comment: See my update. Or consider updating your question to show what you actually try to do. There might be a much better solution...

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. I think you've given me something to think about out. However, now that you mentioned that ad servers would add variables on their end, would I be able to know what variables they're going to add? Maybe the best way is to just create another page to tackle the second variable?

Comment: what if the user puts some other GET variable in the url? `?var=something&var4` instead of var2, they add var4? Is there another way to tackle this?

Comment: Why would you want this? If you don't use that variable you shouldn't care.

Comment: its just if some hacker or something would want to mess around with the URL, they can produce more variables just to see what would happen. If they add more variables, there should be some 404 page or some sort. am i thinking it wrong?

Comment: You are. Adding more variables is not a problem at all. They are just there and won't hurt anyone.